# How to get value of a Tensorflow 4D Tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to get the value of a full feature matrix.

Here is my simplified code

## aTensor is assigned

```
aTensor = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(tf.nn.conv2d(image1, w, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME'),b))
```

## Trying to get detailed data obtained by aTensor

```
print aTensor
```

## I get following

```
Tensor("Relu_1:0", shape=TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(5), Dimension(5), Dimension(8)]), dtype=float32)
```

How can I get the values stored in "`Dimension(5), Dimension(5), Dimension(8)`"?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to understand how tensorflow works in order to understand why you have that issue:

1. First you "build" a graph (imagine you build a chip-layout)
2. Then (later) you throw data at that graph.

THEN (I guess) you want to see what's actually in there. In order to do that, create an additional print-op in the graph (in step 1 above) that will automatically be executed in step 2.

You can see how tf.print works here: [tf.print in the API](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#Print)